# Angular - Unable to $setValidity (is not a function)

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app linked to a Rails a backend.
What I want is to handle Rails validation errors with Angular.

Based on differents tutorials, I did this:

**edit.html**

```
<div id="Wrapper" ng-controller="EditCtrl"
  <div class="row margin-top-100">
      <form name="form">
        <div>

        <!--- FIELD -->
          <input class="field" type="text" ng-blur="update()" ng-model="current.title" name="title">
        </div>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

**edit.js**

```
.controller('EditCtrl', 
      function($scope, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $http, CurrentSpot, $filter, Notification, $modal,$compile, $timeout){

    $scope.update = function() {
      $http.put('/c/'+$scope.current.id.$oid, {c: $scope.current})
      .then(function(success) {

        $scope.current = success.data;
        Notification.success("Great !")

      }, function(error) {
        console.log(error)
        form.title.$setValidity('server', false);
        console.log("FORM", form.title)
      })
    }
})
```

Which produces this error `form.title.$setValidity is not a function` in the console when Rails refused the update.

Maybe one more information: `console.log("FORM", form)` returns:

```
<input class="field ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty" type="text" ng-blur="update()" ng-model="current.title" name="title" >
```

but `{{form.title}}` in the view returns:

```
{
   "$viewValue":"Cc",
   "$modelValue":"Cc",
   "$validators":{

   },
   "$asyncValidators":{

   },
   "$parsers":[

   ],
   "$formatters":[
      null
   ],
   "$viewChangeListeners":[

   ],
   "$untouched":true,
   "$touched":false,
   "$pristine":true,
   "$dirty":false,
   "$valid":true,
   "$invalid":false,
   "$error":{

   },
   "$name":"title",
   "$options":null
}
```

After many hours of reading tutorials and documentations, I'm not able to find where the problem comes from. 
Thanks

Comment: $scope.form.title.$setValidity('server', false);

Comment: I already tried, but it gives me: 'Cannot read property 'title' of undefined' . Thanks for your help

Comment: The first element of the html you posted is missing its closing `>` ... (`<div id="Wrapper" ng-controller="EditCtrl">`).  When you inspect the scope (using angular dev tools), do you see the `form` object there?  Please see [angular form directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form)

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. I changed the code on Stackoverflow a bit for clarity and i forgot the closing >. I looked to the scope with Batarang, and no, I can't see the form object here, but I see it inside a childScope (two scopes after ngController).

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function as `form.title.$setValidity('server', false);`, `form` return DOM object, not an Angular object with `$`-named methods.
Angular creates a object in the `$scope` for the named form.
Check [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cajypu4c/) and take a look at the browser console.

Comment: Thanks for your fiddle. I understand what you mean. But what I can't see is why my $scope.form is returning 'undefined' instead of the Angular object (I just tried again in a console.log, $scope.form == undefined.